# how do I display a featured image in a post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a single-posttype.php and I'm trying to figure out how to display the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need can be found on the Codex documentation page for post thumbnails.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Specifically i think you're looking for..

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Comment: I tried putting that in my post, but nothing showed

Comment: You said **"I have a single-posttype.php and I'm trying to figure out how to display the image"**, and thus my suggestion was toward code to be placed inside that file, `the_post_thumbnail` is a template tag and is required to be used inside the loop(of which, if your single template is like any other, will contain a loop).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
     $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'yourPostTypeName',   /* edit this line */
        'posts_per_page' => 15 ) );
?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>  

     <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This code also doesn't work? I believe you're listing everything fine (titles, excerpts etc.) & thumbnails only doesn't show? How do you add them? Do you see them in down right corner on edit pages?

If not change the_post_thumbnail function to:

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?> 
echo $url
```

is it showing thumbnail's address?

There are two options:

a) you're NOT adding thumbnails (to do so, click "Set featured image", select/upload an image and THEN click "Use as featured image", the image should appear in the right down corner),

b) you have no loop (use my first code on page-posttype.php to create one).

**Please click the icon under the arrows on the left side if somebody helps you, your accept rate is dramatically low and many people don't care about you.**

Comment: <?php 
  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
   the_post_thumbnail();
  } 
 ?>

Comment: Why would I need a loop on the single-posttype.php page? I have a loop that displays all my posts and then when I click on it, I want to display the featured image.

Comment: Also, I have answered 4 posts now, why would it only show 25%?